# Apply function to pandas column having other column as argument

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Hey I am trying to apply a function to a column **x** using **y as parameter**, so for every row I want to apply **x** to **y**, something like this:

```
def fun(x, y):
    return x + y



df['xy'] = df['x'].apply(fun, args = df['y'])
```

But it does not work.
Any ideas?
Note that my real function is not as simple as adding two values

Comment: `df['xy'] = df['x'] + df['y']` ?

Comment: My real function is not that simple

Comment: `df['xy'] = df.apply(lambda row: fun(row['x'], row['y']), axis=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with lambda function and `axis=1` for procesing per rows:

```
df['xy'] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x['x'], x['y']), axis=1)
```

But if possible, better is use vectorized operations, here:

```
df['xy'] = df['x'] + df['y']
```

Comment: @MiguelSantos - yes, it is value from `df['x']`, but scalar, because looping by rows.

Comment: I think it is working, I have to test it further, but I will accept that answer in a bit, thanks

Comment: but by the way you say to apply with axis = 0 but then you applied to axis = 1 in the solution