# Proper way to update pandas dataframe column with function having other columns as arguments

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to numpy and and pandas, so I can't wrap my head around this yet.

I'm trying to store arrays to pandas dataframe column. The arrays are created with a function that take values from other columns as arguments.

*EDIT (5.4.2020): This code is a simplified example used for clarity*

I set up my dataframe like this:

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])

#setting up the dataframe to hold arrays in column 'c'
dt = {'a':'int32','b':'int32','c':'object'}
tdf = tdf.astype(dt)

#inserting data to columns 'a' and 'b'
row = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(1,3),'b':np.arange(3,5)})
tdf = tdf.append(row,sort=False,ignore_index=True)
```

I want to accomplish something like this:

```
tdf.at[0,'c'] = np.arange(tdf.at[0,'a'],2*tdf.at[0,'b'])
tdf.at[1,'c'] = np.arange(tdf.at[1,'a'],2*tdf.at[1,'b'])

# Output is the desired end result:
   a  b                   c
0  1  3     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1  2  4  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

But because I need to do more complex manipulation, I planned to do it inside a function like this:

```
def nar(x,y):
    # more complex processing done than here
    ar = np.array(x,2*y)
    return ar

tdf['c'] = nar(tdf['a'],tdf['b'])

# Not desired end result:
   a  b  c
0  1  4  1
1  2  5  2
```

I have also tried:

```
# Raises TypeError: ('data type not understood', 'occurred at index 0')
tdf['c'] = tdf.apply(lambda x: nar(x['a'], x['b']), axis=1)
```

as suggested to be used for processing per row in ["Apply function to pandas column having other column as argument"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542683/apply-function-to-pandas-column-having-other-column-as-argument).

Also tested:

```
# Raises TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
tdf['c'] = np.array(tdf['a'],2*tdf['b'])

# and
x = np.arange(1,3)
y = np.arange(3,5)

# Raises TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
z = np.arange(x,2*y)
```

That makes me think that dataframe might actually work correctly with nar function, but it's the underlaying numpy that might require different approach.

Iterating through the rows with `iterrows()` is an option, but it is not very elegant and it also goes with a warning not to modify anything you are iterating over.

What is a proper way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Properly*, I'd suggest you completely rethink storing lists, or arrays, in a DataFrame. DataFrames are meant to be 2D rectangular containers of scalar values. Once you start storing more complicated and nested objects you lose a lot of the optimization. Why do you need lists in the DataFrame, and what do you plan to do with them later? Likely it wont be easy anymore.

Comment: I'm doing statistical analysis on different type of curve fitting methods on a certain type data. Results will be goodness of fit values and runtimes, but i would like to store the (randomly) generated data and (varying number) of parameters with the results. Most of the analysis is done based on goodness of fit and runtime scalars, but I'm sure there will be outliers that I want to study more closely. If I could store all the data relating to a single run to a row in data frame, I hopefully could keep it well organized and in sync. And also could save it to disk easily when running batches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed at your nar function:

```
def nar(x,y):
    # more complex processing done than here
    ar = np.arange(x,2*y)
    return ar

tdf['c'] = tdf.apply(lambda x: nar(x['a'], x['b']), axis=1)
```

You wrote array instead of arange

Comment: Yes I did, but unfortunately that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry! There was a mistake in my answer, can you try now? For me, it's working perfectly now @PSm

Comment: Works now, Thank You @bruno-mello! And it works with my actual function too. So, it was actually mainly that darn array <-> arange issue in my original simple test function that messed things up. The .apply(lambda..) line looks the same in your solution as it was in my original post. It's strange how you can't see so obvious mistakes in your own code. Was a long Friday though… I blame it on that :D

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the help of `apply`.

```py
tdf['c'] = tdf.apply(lambda row: list(range(row["a"], 2 * row["b"])) ,axis = 1)
```

output:

```
   a  b                   c
0  1  3     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1  2  4  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

One caveat though, `apply` is very slow when it comes to large datasets.

Comment: You can replace this list(range()) by a np.arange(), it is a little more pythonic

Comment: I wanted to emulate the "exact" behavior where I wanted to return `list`. `np.arange` will keep it as array while just `range` will make it a `tuple`. Apart from that yes!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I have to point out that I want to do more complex manipulation than in the example function (see comment in the function). I'm not sure I can do all that I need to do with a single lambda function and that's why I'm trying to do this with a proper function.
But I am trying to store numpy arrays not lists, if that changes things…